# python beautifulsoup select, how to get specific values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I just wanna get '281'.
It's last page value.

code:

```
<div class="page2"><a href="#" onclick="goPage('1'); return false;">
<img alt="First-Page" border="0" src="/images/ic_arrow_first.gif"/></a>
<a href="#" onclick="goPage('1'); return false;"><span> 1 </span></a>
<a href="#" onclick="goPage('41'); return false;"><span> 2 </span></a>
<a href="#" onclick="goPage('81'); return false;"><span> 3 </span></a>
<a href="#" onclick="goPage('121'); return false;"><span> 4 </span></a>
<span class="page_on">5</span>
<a href="#" onclick="goPage('201'); return false;"><span> 6 </span></a>
<a href="#" onclick="goPage('241'); return false;"><span> 7 </span></a>
<a href="#" onclick="goPage('281'); return false;"><span> 8 </span></a>
<a href="#" onclick="goPage('281'); return false;">
<img alt="Last Page" border="0" src="/images/ic_arrow_last.gif"/></a></div>
```

Comment: By what criteria do you want to get `281`? Please put a bit more flesh on the bones of what you have in mind of how identifying 281 is supposed to be done?

Comment: OK, I would like to get last page value

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your current code, and explain what it does at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
s = """<div class="page2"><a href="#" onclick="goPage('1'); return false;"><img alt="First-Page" border="0" src="/images/ic_arrow_first.gif"/></a><a href="#" onclick="goPage('1'); return false;"><span> 1 </span></a><a href="#" onclick="goPage('41'); return false;"><span> 2 </span></a><a href="#" onclick="goPage('81'); return false;"><span> 3 </span></a><a href="#" onclick="goPage('121'); return false;"><span> 4 </span></a><span class="page_on">5</span><a href="#" onclick="goPage('201'); return false;"><span> 6 </span></a><a href="#" onclick="goPage('241'); return false;"><span> 7 </span></a><a href="#" onclick="goPage('281'); return false;"><span> 8 </span></a><a href="#" onclick="goPage('281'); return false;"><img alt="Last Page" border="0" src="/images/ic_arrow_last.gif"/></a></div>"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
val = soup.find_all("a")[-1]["onclick"]    #Get the last element using negative indexing.
m = re.search("\((.*?)\)", val)   #Regex to get content inside "()"
if m:
    print(m.group())    #Or print(m.group(1)) --> '281'
```

**Output:**

```
('281')
```

Comment: Guess the question is... is it definitely the last `a` tag or is it the one  preceding the `img` with the `alt="Last Page"` attribute... probably doesn't matter but...